# Find fantasy novel involving fairies, magic and tattoos that harm humans

Tags: story-identification

I have been trying to remember the title of a book I read a while back and hope someone can help. The story involved a woman who was magical, I believe she was a fairy herself who had been exiled, and there was a male fairy who operated a tattoo shop and his tattoos harmed or took energy from the humans. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds a bit like "[Ink Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ink_Exchange)" by Melissa Marr

> *Seventeen-year-old Leslie knows nothing of faeries or their intrigues. When she is attracted to an eerily beautiful tattoo of eyes
>   and wings, all she knows is that she has to have it, convinced it is a
>   tangible symbol of changes she desperately craves for her own life.
>
> The tattoo does bring changes—not the kind Leslie has dreamed of, but
>   sinister, compelling changes that are more than symbolic. Those
>   changes will bind Leslie and Irial together, drawing Leslie deeper and
>   deeper into the faery world, unable to resist its allures, and
>   helpless to withstand its perils. . . .*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this what you're looking for but Robin McKinley's [Sunshine](http://www.robinmckinley.com/books/) novel involves a female protagonist and magical tattoos. Great book in any case.

Comment: No fairies there, great book indeed.